# php array echo out array object

Tags: php, arrays, object

How to echo out "username taken" from this array?

```
array(2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "username taken"
    [1]=>
    string(20) "email already in use"
  }
  ["error"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: Using php you can do it, be sure!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
//define the array
$array = array("data"=>array("username taken","email already in use"),array("error"=>NULL));
//output full array
var_dump($array);
//output first element of data
echo "<br>".$array["data"][0];
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'data'

Comment: yeh that works.. i'm not a complete noob i think  i found out why this wasn't working for me when i trying it.. it seems this junk api it returning a string that just happens to look like an array.. string(154) "array(2) { ["data"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "username taken" [1]=> string(20) "email already in use" } ["error"]=> NULL } "

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $variableNameOfArray["data"]["0"];
```

Should do the trick.